# Java problem with Visualworkflow after release

Tags: visual-workflow

In trying to run a Visual Workflow this morning (after our SF upgrade), we began getting a strange error:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.SObjectRow

We have not made any changes to the flow to cause this response.  I've isolated the error to a "Fast Lookup" element which finds a number of records from a custom object and assigns them to an SObject Collection variable.  Again, all was working fine when I last tried it on Friday.

Any thoughts or feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words from Process Automation product manager "**Arnab Bose**"

We have a fix in progress - should be coming out soon.

Reference:- https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003HY37Q?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&s1uid=00530000007qXzi&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1508194281271&OpenCommentForEdit=1

[image]